# Android sendBroadcastAsUser() UserHandle.USER_CURRENT error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-broadcast

I am rebuilding an Android app for which I've the source code from the OEM. Normally, the app can be using the `make` command in command line and that works. The app's UI, manifest etc. is done in Eclipse. But Eclipse can't compile the app, and gives error on the line shown below and does't recognize the item `USER_CURRENT`.

```
 sendBroadcastAsUser(exampleIntent, new UserHandle(UserHandle.USER_CURRENT));
```

Does anyone know how can I build and run the app from Eclipse?

Btw, I build my own system image for the platform using Android 4.4.2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used

```
android.os.Process.myUserHandle()
```

to get UserHandle instance.